# How to capture and process system events in minko?

Tags: android, events, onresume, onpause, minko

Is it possible to get system events such as for Android Activity life cycle events (onCreate, onStart, onPause, onResume...) in [Minko](http://minko.io) ?

I can see in Canvas.hpp for example :

```
 Signal<AbstractCanvas::Ptr, uint, uint>::Ptr    _resized;
```

and

```
Signal<AbstractCanvas::Ptr, std::shared_ptr<input::Joystick>>::Ptr   _joystickAdded;
Signal<AbstractCanvas::Ptr, std::shared_ptr<input::Joystick>>::Ptr   _joystickRemoved;
```

which I believe are "system" events being sent to the app, but i can't seem to find the ones i am looking for, or should i be looking in another class ?

For example, the **audio** example of the frameworks plays perfectly on Android phone but keep on playing the music after the activity / application has exited "visually"  . (it only ends if you manually kill the running process)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK those events are not implemented in Minko yet. It should be fairly easy though if SDL provides them. Here is the list of all the SDL events:

https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_EventType

I'm pretty sure some of them might fit your needs. It should be pretty simple to handle them in [Canvas::step()](https://github.com/aerys/minko/blob/master/plugin/sdl/src/minko/Canvas.cpp#L325) by dispatching a signal.

If you need help, create a feature request [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/aerys/minko/issues) and we'll help.